# Does a basis span even linear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understood basis as a set of vector $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}$ as the set whose linear combination will span the entire vector space say $ \mathbb R^{n}$ which makes perfect sense in intuitive terms. There are $n$ independent vectors, linear combination spans the entire space and the dimensions equals the number of linearly independent vector.

But I came across a very interesting question, which asked, *is this a vector space? If yes, then find its dimension and basis.* and asks this about,

- all skew symmetric matrices of $2 \times 2$ dimension

Its interesting to note, it is associative,commutative under addition operator and scaling of the same is a subset of the same space. (do correct me if my choice of words is right here)

Which implies its a vector space, with a basis of $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$
That implies dimension is 1.

So my question is, if basis indeed can span a linear system (represented by the matrix)?
If my interpretation is right, then can anyone give me an intuitive "feel" of the basis, dimension and vector space.

Help much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "linear system"?

Comment: A matrix represents a linear system isnt it? So a vector space can even represent a space of matrices which follow a certain property as shown above.

Comment: A matrix represents a lot of things. A vector space can be _any set_ which is equipped with the appropriate operations, and that includes sets of matrices.

Comment: Yes, after doing this sum, thats what seems so, but I was sturggling to form a coherent physical feel of "basis" , as it can even "span" a set of linear systems

Comment: Possibly related : (Although remotely) http://math.stackexchange.com/q/116717/22386

Comment: @Nunoxic Mucho thanks. Appreciated!

Comment: A basis has to have **two** properties: (i) the span must equal the entire space; and (ii) the set must be linearly independent. Also, most vector spaces have more than one basis, so it makes no sense to talk about "finding *the* basis" for a vector space.

Comment: Why vote to close an answer which is over a year old with a perfectly fine answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qiaochu Yuan answered the question.